# Strange Behavior of top nav bar in IE

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a new navigation bar for our site. Works great in Chrome, but in IE it is doing something strange. When you mouseover a menu that has a sub-menu, the sub-menu appears alright, but when you try to move over the sub menu, it closes!

Has anyone had any similar experience? Is there something that I can change in the css setting so it normalizes?

here's the css code for the nav bar:

```css
>      <style type="text/css">
>      nav {    
>        display: block;
>        text-align: center;
>      }
>      nav ul {
>        margin: 0;
>        padding:0;
>        list-style: none;
>      }
>      .nav a {
>        display:block; 
>        background: #111; 
>        color: #fff; 
>        text-decoration: none;
>        padding: 0.2em 1.8em;
>        text-transform: uppercase;
>        font-size: 80%;
>        letter-spacing: 1px;
>        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
>        position: relative;
>      }
>      .nav{  
>        vertical-align: top; 
>        display: inline-block;
>        box-shadow: 
>          1px -1px -1px 1px #000, 
>          -1px 1px -1px 1px #fff, 
>          0 0 6px 3px #fff;
>        border-radius:6px;
>      }
>      .nav li {
>        position: relative;
>      }
>      .nav > li { 
>        float: left; 
>        border-bottom: 4px #aaa solid; 
>        margin-right: 1px; 
>      } 
>      .nav > li > a { 
>        margin-bottom: 1px;
>        box-shadow: inset 0 2em .33em -0.5em #555; 
>      }
>      .nav > li:hover, 
>      .nav > li:hover > a { 
>        border-bottom-color: orange;
>      }
>      .nav li:hover > a { 
>        color:orange; 
>      }
>      .nav > li:first-child { 
>        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
>      } 
>      .nav > li:first-child > a { 
>        border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
>      }
>      .nav > li:last-child { 
>        border-radius: 0 0 4px 0; 
>        margin-right: 0;
>      } 
>      .nav > li:last-child > a { 
>        border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
>      }
>      .nav li li a { 
>        margin-top: 1px;
>      }
>  
>      // then... The magic happens....
>  
>  
>      .nav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
>        content: ""; 
>        position: absolute; 
>        height: 0; 
>        width: 0; 
>        border: 5px solid transparent; 
>        top: 50% ;
>        right:5px;  
>       }
>  
>  
>  
>      /* submenu positioning*/
>      .nav ul {
>        position: absolute;
>        white-space: nowrap;
>        border-bottom: 5px solid  orange;
>        z-index: 1;
>       left: -99999em;
>      }
>      .nav > li:hover > ul {
>        left: auto;
>        margin-top: 5px;
>        min-width: 100%;
>      }
>      .nav > li li:hover > ul { 
>        left: 100%;
>        margin-left: 1px;
>        top: -1px;
>      }
>      /* arrow hover styling */
>      .nav > li > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
>        border-top-color: #aaa; 
>      }
>      .nav > li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
>        border: 5px solid transparent; 
>        border-bottom-color: orange; 
>        margin-top:-5px
>      }
>      .nav li li > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {  
>        border-left-color: #aaa; 
>        margin-top: -5px
>      }
>      .nav li li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
>        border: 5px solid transparent; 
>        border-right-color: orange;
>        right: 10px; 
>      }
>  
>  
>  
>      </style>
```

And the navigation bar itself:

```html
>  <nav>
>        <ul class="nav">
>          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
>          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
>            <ul>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
>            </ul>
>          </li>
>          <li><a href="#">Resume</a>
>            <ul>
>              <li><a href="#">item a lonng submenu</a></li>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a>
>                <ul>
>                  <li><a href="#">Ray</a></li>
>                  <li><a href="#">Veronica</a></li>
>                  <li><a href="#">Bushy</a></li>
>                  <li><a href="#">Havoc</a></li>
>                </ul>
>              </li>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
>            </ul>
>          </li>
>          <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
>          <li><a href="#">Rants</a>
>            <ul>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
>              <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
>            </ul>
>          </li>
>          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
>        </ul>
>      </nav>
```

And finally, A link to the webpage... [My new Navigation bar](http://examscan.us/shulemberger/new_nav.php)

Comment: What version of IE?  I'm getting intended results on 11.

Comment: Earlier versions of IE might have problems with the `<nav>` element. Try using `<div>` instead